# #include recursion with template

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, linker-errors

I have problem like there [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) (and there  [Correct way of structuring CMake based project with Template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687311/correct-way-of-structuring-cmake-based-project-with-template-class)) but with include recursion.

Code:

A.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

struct A
{
    B b;
    void doThingA() {}
};
```

B.h

```cpp
#pragma once
struct A;

struct B
{
    A *a;
    template<typename T>
    void doThingB();
};

#include "A.h"

template<typename T>
void B::doThingB()
{
    a->doThingA();
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.h"

int main() {}
```

Error:

```cpp
In file included from A.h:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
B.h: In member function 'void B::doThingB()':
B.h:16:6: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A'
   16 |     a->doThingA();
      |      ^~
B.h:2:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct A'
    2 | struct A;
      |        ^
```

`B.h` includes from `A.h` but `A.h` required by template function implementation in `B.h` does not. I'm also cannot take implementation to an `.cpp` because of template.

It's possible to solve by using explicit instantiation of templates but I'm wondering for another solution.

Comment: Why are both types so closely linked together? Could it possibly be more meaningful just to keep both of them in the *same* header?

Comment: @Aconcagua in real project I'm doing Unity-like game engine where `A` is `GameEngine` class and `B` is `Entity` which has methods `Add|GetComponent<T>()`. I'm using `GameEngine` as container and linker for various systems so many of them have reference to `GameEngine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have types that are this tightly coupled, the simplest solution is to put them in a single header file.

```
#pragma once

// forward declaration of A
struct A;

// declare B, since A needs it
struct B
{
    A *a;
    template<typename T>
    void doThingB();
};

// now we can declare A
struct A
{
    B b;
    void doThingA() {}
};

// and finally, implement the parts of B that need A
// and need to be in the header
template<typename T>
void B::doThingB()
{
    a->doThingA();
}
```

If you still want a `B.h`, then it can be a single line:

```
#include "A.h"
```

If you want to split `A`/`B` into multiple headers for your own organization, a simple solution is to add compile-time checks to ensure the files aren't included directly.

```
// A.h
#pragma once

#define A_IMPL

#include "B_impl.h"

#undef A_IMPL
```

```
// B.h
#pragma once

#ifndef A_IMPL

#error "B_impl.h can't be included directly; use A.h"

#endif

struct A;

struct B
{
    A *a;
    template<typename T>
    void doThingB();
};

#include "A_impl.h"

template<typename T>
void B::doThingB()
{
    a->doThingA();
}
```

```
// A_impl.h
#pragma once

#ifndef A_IMPL

#error "A_impl.h can't be included directly; use A.h"

#endif

struct A
{
    B b;
    void doThingA() {}
};
```

You can make the `#ifdef` checks more complicated if you want more of your headers to use the impl files directly, but the public interface remains blissfully unaware.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stephen's solution I came up with that architecture:

A.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#define A_H
#include "B.h"

struct A
{
    B b;
    void doThingA() {}
};

#include "B_impl.h"
```

B.h

```cpp
#pragma once
struct A;

struct B
{
    A *a;
    template <typename T>
    void doThingB();
};

#ifndef A_H
#include "B_impl.h"
#endif
```

B_impl.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

template <typename T>
void B::doThingB()
{
    a->doThingA();
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.h"

int main() {}
```

So I can include `A.h` and `B.h` separately and also it looks cleaner for me.